# Reemplazar grupos expresión regular JAVA

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentando de realizar un reemplazo por grupos, no se si es posible hacer con una sola expresión

**Texto**

`String linea = "[[A, _, _, _, A], [_, A, _, A, _]]";`

**Texto esperado**

`String linea = "A _ _ _ A\n_ A _ A _";`

Expresión regular: `(\[\[)(,)(],)(]])`

Prueba #1
`String lineaFinal = linea.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)(,)(],)(]])", "$1 ,$2,$3\n,$4")`

Prueba #2
`String lineaFinal = linea.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)(,)(],)(]])", " ,,\n,")`

Comment: Tengo entendido que puedes reemplazar el resto y mantener el grupo, tendrías que invertir tu expresión, en todo caso te recomiendo colocar un ejemplo completo reproducible en un bloque de código de tu problema y el resultado que obtienes con tu codigo

Answer (score 1):

La única forma que encuentro yo de hacerlo con el método `.replaceAll` es haciéndolo en dos partes como mínimo.

```
linea = linea.replaceAll("\\](,)\\s","\n");
linea = linea.replaceAll("\\[|,|\\]", "");
```

En el primer reemplazo se pone el salto de línea y en el segundo se suprimen los corchetes y las comas.

Answer (score 0):

El string de salida presenta dos cambios: a veces sustituye por '' y otras veces por '\n'. Eso se llama sustitución condicional y no es soportada por java.

De hecho, hay pocos motores de expresiones regulares que lo soporten (Boost para C++ es uno de ellos, por ejemplo)

Como java no soporta sustituciones condicionales, y haces dos tipos de sustituciones, **siempre** vas a necesitar dos remplazos.

Una alternativa que soportan otros lenguajes de programación es pasar un método/función al remplazar el texto. Esa función se llamará cada vez que se haga un remplazo, con lo que puedes utilizar la lógica que necesites y personalizar el remplazo a tus necesidades.

Por ejemplo, en ese método mirarías si lo que te llega es `], [` entonces remplazarías por salto de línea, y si no, por nada.

Aquí tienes un [ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback.php) de como funcionaría en php, solo por tenerlo como referencia.

Desafortunadamente, java no soporta callbacks en los métodos para remplazar texto, así que tampoco sirve.

Sin embargo, java tiene el método [appendReplacement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_matcher_appendreplacement.htm) que permitiría emular algo parecido. [Aquí](https://gist.github.com/nickrussler/42f8619f1a36eea25364) tienes un ejemplo.

En cualquier caso, todo esto aumenta la cantidad de líneas a añadir para conseguirlo hacer en una única expresión regular y al final será una solución mucho más compleja que hacer dos simples remplazos.

**No hay nada de malo en hacer dos o más remplazos sencillos en lugar de uno más complejo** (de hecho, puede ser preferible, ya que facilita el posterior mantenimiento del código)